# Remove all 3rd party apps and software

Tags: xampp, reset

I install many known and unknown software. Now I got a problem. Mysql and apache server can't be open. I install and re-install xampp server but not working anymore. Now I want to uninstall all software that I installed and reset my system without deleting any video and others file. I can't format my pc because there are many resources that I collected. So please give me a solution.

Comment: It is the "unknown" software that is the biggest problem which has made "uknown" modifications to configuration files. You really would save yourself alot of time and trouble by backing up your data and spend 20 minutes to reinstall a clean system.

Comment: how can I clean my pc

Comment: Can I backup my file on my pc. Because I can't back up in online

Comment: @ammasum It's recommended to backup to different media as re-installation may overwrite your backup if it's on the same drive/partition that you are installing to. You might find this useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools